# Can't delete a file inside S3 Bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have a web app that enables users to make posts that contain files, these files are hosted using AWS S3 Buckets. (I'm using Node.js + Express)

Users can successfully post files and retrieve them, but the problem relies in deleting a file, as I get an "Access Denied" response.

Although when I created the S3 Bucket, I've allowed the Put, Get, and Delete permissions. And to verify that, I've copied the JSON from access-policy section:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::saud-demo-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And to also verify that the credentials and the data passed in my node.js app are correct, I've placed `console.log()` statements to see the data passed into the `getFileFromS3()` function and the `deleteFileFromS3()` function:

**Get file from S3 Bucket:**

```
async function getFileFromS3(req) {

  console.log("REQ.QUERY.S3FILENAME IN GET FUNCTION IS:");
  console.log(req.query.s3FileName);

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: req.query.s3FileName,
  };

  const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
  const file = await s3.send(command);

  if (file.$metadata.httpStatusCode === 200) {
    console.log("File retreived successfully!");
    return {
      success: true,
      file,
    };
  } else {
    console.log("Error retreiving file ..");
    return {
      err: true,
      file,
    };
  }
}
```

**Delete file from S3 Bucket:**

```
async function deleteFileFromS3(req) {
  console.log("REQ.QUERY.S3FILENAME IN DELETE FUNCTION IS:");
  console.log(req.query.s3FileName);

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: req.query.s3FileName,
  };

  const command = new DeleteObjectCommand(params);
  const result = await s3.send(command);

  if (result.$metadata.httpStatusCode === 200) {
    console.log("File deleted successfully!");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("Error deleting file ..");
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
[nodemon] starting `node server/server.js`
Listening ...
Connected to database successfully!
REQ.QUERY.S3FILENAME IN GET FUNCTION IS:
5e55c3065c73e828dfe2a5e1c1cf777f8ad9235b8cf3dbbcf6572f03979b32cb.docx
File retreived successfully!
REQ.QUERY.S3FILENAME IN DELETE FUNCTION IS:
5e55c3065c73e828dfe2a5e1c1cf777f8ad9235b8cf3dbbcf6572f03979b32cb.docx
(node:15800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at throwDefaultError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folders\Dev\Web\Projects\seu-students\node_modules\@aws-sdk\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:8:22)
```

I don't have experience in s3 buckets, and I haven't messed with something at all, I just followed a tutorial on how to do so.

So how can I tackle this issue?

Comment: Looks like this is IAM permission issue. Similar  question has already raised. You can check this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620873/why-is-my-access-denied-on-s3-using-the-aws-sdk-for-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by deleting then re-creating the IAM user (which in this case is my web app) who is accessing the S3 bucket.

Seems that I've done something wrong the first time I created the IAM user and attached the policies.

I'm following a tutorial so I might missed a step or something.